# res.cookie is undefined when server uses HTTPS

Tags: node.js, express, https

I'm using a user login logic that saves JWT in cookies.

```
const token = jwt.sign({
  username: login,
},
  process.env.JWT_SECRET);

res.cookie("jwt", token, {
  secure: false,
  httpOnly: true,
});
console.log(res)
return res.status(200).json({
  success: true,
  username: login });
```

The frontend making requests runs oh HTTP. When the server runs also on HTTP, everything works fine, but when I go for HTTPS, the cookie is not saved at all. Setting 'secure' to true does not help. What can be the possible reason?

Comment: How did you determine the cookie is not saved? Did you check if it appears on subsequent requests? The httpOnly flag causes the cookie to not be accessible programmatically, so it may appear like the cookie is empty when just checking via the console

Comment: I check in the browser and they are not there. Exactly the same code works perfectly for HTTP. 
Perhaps I should mention that the frontend making requests runs on HTTP. Can it be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

```
use secure: true,
```

in your response for cookie

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: As I wrote in the question: "Setting 'secure' to true does not help."

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem lately and here is my solution for this problem.

I change my res.cookie to this

```
res.cookie("jwt", token, {
      secure: true,
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "None", // I add this line
});
```